# url field is not getting recognised in Watson Discovery service during conversion

Tags: url, watson, discovery

Inline with this thread 
[How do we get the document file url using the Watson Discovery Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41909962/how-do-we-get-the-document-file-url-using-the-watson-discovery-service/41940944#41940944),

I tried adding url field inside HTML document under various tags like p, directly as

<"url">...<"/url">  etc inside <"body"> tag.

Whatever I do, this url field that I am trying to add is not getting reflected either under extracted_metadata or under html or under text in the json when I see the resulting json after conversion / enrichment in the discovery tooling. Can someone throw some hint on what I can do to get url field just like title under extracted_metadata section in the json output?

Comment: Guys, any hints on this? I dont have a clue as to how I can proceed. I have tried out pretty much every format in HTML for the discovery service to recognize my url link.