# How can I view the actual documents returned in IBM Discovery Service Query

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-discovery

I have an IBM Watson Discovery Service on my Bluemix account.  I have been poking around the web for the last hour trying to find out how I can view the document(s) that are returned in my query results.

Is it even possible?  If not, how do you get a URL in there when you upload a document?  Are people just getting the filename and then creating a link on the fly to a folder on the server that has the document in it?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41940944/456564

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do we get the document file url using the Watson Discovery Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41909962/how-do-we-get-the-document-file-url-using-the-watson-discovery-service)

Comment: Actually, I believe that may be the answer as well as a duplicate.  I will verify the actuality of it.